# Run multiple jobs in parallels and wait until all of them finished

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, jobs, laravel-artisan

I have a large array of items and I want to make calculations with them. But it takes too much time to process it in sync. How can I run async jobs in Laravel?

What I want is to split this array to chunks and process all of them at the same time and wait until all of these jobs will be finished and go on to the next operations.

For now what i do:

1. define main_key for this job
2. split array to chunks
3. for every chunk create new job and dispatch it in $uniqueQueueName
4. for every unique queue run workers with running

```php
exec('php artisan queue:work --queue=$uniqueQueueName --once --stop-when-empty .... >> asyncWorker.log &')
```

5. when job processing is started - it increments value for main_key in the cache (In Async)
6. when job processing is finished or failed with error - it decrements value for main_key in the cache and removes main_key from the cache when value == 0 (In Async)
7. while main_key exists in cache wait 1 second
8. move on...

```php
$syncStatsKey = 'MainJobKey';

$chunks = Collection::make($items)->chunk(100);
        foreach ($chunks as $i => $chunk) {

            $queueName = $syncStatsKey.'_'.$i.'_'.now()->getTimestamp();
            dispatch(new SyncStats($chunk,$syncStatsKey))->onQueue($queueName);
            $artisanPath = base_path('artisan');
            $logPath = storage_path('logs/AsyncWorkers.log');
            $commandString = "php $artisanPath queue:work --queue=$queueName --memory=512 --sleep=0 --timeout=600 --tries=1 --once --stop-when-empty >> $logPath &";

            exec($commandString);
        }

while (\Cache::has($syncStatsKey)) {
     sleep(1)
}
```

**Why not to use Artisan::call('queue:work',[$params]) ?** - its returns only when queue work is finished, instead of exec('php artisan ... &')

**Why not to send all these jobs to one default queue with workers supervised by Horizon?** - This scheme consumes too many resources. Sometimes array is split into 200 chunks and all of them should be processed at the same time. For this at least 200 workers should monitor the default queue. But Horizon doesn't create workers dynamically, it keeps all of them running all the time.

I have a strong filling that what I'm doing is not the right way to solve my problem.
Are there any other ways to do what I want?

Comment: Would it be good to count the amount of jobs. Then, using `Cache`, increment a`completed_jobs` key which you can then check `$jobCount == Cache::get('completed_jobs')`. If the check fails, check again later.

Comment: Thats how it works right now. The only difference is that incrementing and decrementing fires from job handle() method

Comment: Apologies. Then I would think that a separate job should be fired along side this process which does this comparion. If still processing, it should delete itself and fire off a new job to start again.